# Strange image from Android camera stream

Tags: javascript, android, camera, video-streaming, tokbox

I am building an application for video calls and I have one strange image from the Android stream after 5-6 minutes of talk only for one phone. I am using [tokbox](https://tokbox.com/) and this photo is not in the lib (for errors).

User 1 (Android) can see his stream and stream of User 2 (JS), but User 2 can see his stream and this photo (instead of User 1 stream).

Have anyone seen this before? I cannot find anything related to this one.

[image: From android stream]

[image: Thermometer photo from stream]

Comment: device is too hot to take a picture, check temperature

Comment: Looks like that, but is it possible the phone it self to sent this as a stream to the JS app?